# iOS HTML to PDF Library

Tags: html, ios, pdf, ios4

Does anyone know of a library for iOS platform that converts HTML to PDF? I need fairly basic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating my own PDF. It is quite easy to do with Quartz2D. Still happy to know if anyone knows a good library.